# Adding noise to an image with a limited palette

Tags: palette, noise

Backstory: I am designing the pattern in PhotoShop of a quilt my wife is making. The quilt is made of 15x20 squares of exactly six shades of blue - dark at one end to light at the other end. The gradient will be "noisy". I want to experiment with that noise.

So, I have an image that is 15x20 pixels, and I have reduced the palette to exactly 6 colours.

The problem is that, with an exact palette I can't apply any filters such as the noise filter. It's just not available. Dead-end.

I tried Posterize, but Posterize chooses its own colours, often choosing grey. Another dead-end.

The attached sample was done manually. I want a truer noisy gradient that I can experiment with.

Suggestions?

[image]

---

EDIT:

@Billy Kerr:

This is what I get when I follow your directions exactly.

[image]

I started with an RGB image, and I'm using PS CC.

I've experimented with every one of the settings - and that is the *best* I get.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something similar to this, semi automatically.

Create a simple gradient between the darkest and lightest blue and apply it to your 15*20px image.

Something like this:

[image]

Do *Image > Mode > Indexed*, and choose the settings shown:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried local palette. Now that I have I didn't get anything resembling what you did, it was way too non-random, but I'll experiment.

Comment: @DaveC426913 - Hmm, make sure you start with an RGB image, the results may be dependent on what version of Photoshop you have. This is Photoshop CC

Comment: I am using Photoshop CC and starting with an RBG image.

Comment: +1 I was thinking Index Mode as well. @DaveC426913 are you setting the `Dither` to `Noise`? I get [pretty much the same image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqoV6.png) as Billy.

Comment: Yes. Dither=Noise.

Comment: @DaveC426913 - not sure what else you could try to be honest. This works for me, and Scott can replicate it too.